# Promise Ionic/Angular - user connection

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-promise

I'm trying to use promise in order to connect user on my Ionic App.
I tried many things... but that doesn't work. What's the problem ? Can you help me please ?

I have to execute my load function before verify "access".

This is my code currently. What's wrong ? (Currently, the error is : "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.")

This is my load function (no problem whith it, it's what I must execute in first)

```
load(credentials) 
   {

    let headers       : any     = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    options     : any       = { "pseudo" : credentials.email, "mdp" : credentials.password },
    url       : any   = "http://localhost:8888/authVerif2.php" ;


    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      this.http
      .post(url, JSON.stringify(options), headers)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.dir(data);
        this.infosUser = data;
        //console.log(this.infosUser[0].prenom);
      resolve(this.infosUser);

    },


    (error : any) =>
    {
      console.dir(error);
    });

   })
  }
```

This is my login function :

```
public login(credentials) : Observable<any>{
      this.load(credentials)
      .then( a =>
        {


          if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
            return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
          } else {
            return Observable.create(observer => {
              // At this point make a request to your backend to make a real check!      


              let access = (credentials.password === "pass" && credentials.email === "email");
              this.currentUser = new User('Simon', 'saimon@devdactic.com');
              observer.next(access);
              observer.complete();


            });
          }
        }
        );
  }
```

these two functions are in a provider named "auth-service".
This provider is use in my page "login.html"

```
public login() {
    this.showLoading()
    this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(allowed => {
      if (allowed) {        
        this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
      } else {
        this.showError("Access Denied");
      }
    },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: are you check login throw postman

Answer (score 2):

Do not stringify **options** beacause you have to post data to your login function in object format, if you stringify the **options** ,it means you are posting a string. so, you can't access data in login function from credentials.email & credentials.password

Comment: Ok why not. But that doesn't solve my problem. I have to execute one method before the other, otherwise, I have an "undefined property" (because of asynchronous execution)

Comment: http.post call always returns Observable so do not create **Observable.create** like this.

Comment: Ok good idea. But the error appears in my second login function (the last code). "subscribe" is highlighted. The error exist only when I try to use promises. In fact, if I don't use **"this.load(credentials).then( () =>...)"** in my provider, I don't have the error.